# removing singularity

Tags: plotting, singularity

i got help from other members to plot this equation. but there is still a problem. when i plot this equation.

```
    eq = -1.94178*10^24*H*Te^0.5 - (3.2*(7.33376*10^27*Te^(7/2) + 
  4.66533*10^24*Ti^(7/2)))/
  (10^9*H) + 7.68161*10^40*H*(5.41/((10^15*E^(148/Ti))*Ti^(3/2)) + 
 2.00122/((10^10*E^((53.124*(1 - (-0.059357*Ti + 0.0010404*Ti^2 - 
   (9.1653*Ti^3)/10^6)/
      (1 + 0.20165*Ti + 0.0027621*Ti^2 + 
  (9.8305*Ti^3)/10^7))^(1/3))/Ti^(1/3)))*
  (Ti^(2/3)*(1 - (-0.059357*Ti + 0.0010404*Ti^2 - 
(9.1653*Ti^3)/10^6)/
   (1 + 0.20165*Ti + 0.0027621*Ti^2 + (9.8305*Ti^3)/10^7))^(5/6))));

 sol = H /. Solve[eq == 0, H] // Simplify;
```

it seems there is singularity on the left side of the plot. 
How can I solve the issue?
when I want to add ContourLabels it causes problem. 
so first i need to remove the singularity and then add countorlabel

```
c = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
  19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25};

ContourPlot[sol[[2]], {Ti, 1, 1000}, {Te, 1, 160}, Contours -> c, 
ColorFunction -> "GrayTones", PlotPoints -> 100, 
FrameLabel -> {Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(i\)]\)(keV)", 
FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(e\)]\)(keV)", FontSize -> 14, 
FontFamily -> "Times"]}, 
LabelStyle -> {Directive[Black, Bold], (FontSize -> 16), 
 FontFamily -> "Times"}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, 
  LegendLabel -> 
  Style["\[Rho]R(g.\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(cm\), \(-2\)]\))", 
  FontSize -> 12]], {After, Center}], 
  ContourLabels -> (Text[#3, {#1, #2}, Background -> White] &), 
  Background -> White] &)]
```

Comment: Experiment with `WorkingPrecision`  and `Exclusions ` where `1/sol[[2]]`  or denominator is equal zero.

Comment: thank you very much. it helped me.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the existence of a deep valley to the left and an excursion to $-\infty$. With this command

```
Quiet@ContourPlot[Max[Chop[(sol[[2]] + Conjugate[sol[[2]]])/2], -10000], {Ti, 1, 1000}, {Te, 1, 100}, Contours -> 10, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

we obtain the contour

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for the comment. it helped me